# Post and Get value by jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pdo

How can I add my values owdid and visited id after clicking below link by ajax?

```
<a href="index.php" onclick="insertvisit(<?php echo $interestid;?>)">member1</a>
```

Below is my insertvisit function. I have defined owdid and interestid

```
function insertvisit(visitedid) {
  $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: 'insertvisit.php',
       data:{'field1' : owdid, 'field2' : visitedid},
       success:function(html) {
       }
  });
}
```

and below is insertvisit.php

```
global $pdo;
$ownid = $_GET['field1'];
$interestid =$_GET['field2'];

$query = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE tablem SET field1= ? WHERE field2= ?");
$query -> bindValue(1, $ownid);
$query -> bindValue(2, $interestid);
$query -> execute();
```

Please help thanks.

Comment: you are calling post request not get, so need to change `$_GET` to `$_POST`

Comment: You also need to cancel the default event for when you click on a link. Is that all of your `insertvisit.php`? If it is, you will not have a database connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass both value in function with , separated and also you need to change your function call like bellow

```
<a href="index.php" onclick="insertvisit(<?php echo $interestid.','.$owdid;?>)">member1</a>
```

And your function :

```
function insertvisit(visitedid,owdid) {
   $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: 'insertvisit.php',
           data:{'field1' : owdid, 'field2' : visitedid},
           success:function(html) {
           }
   });
}
```

and also you need to change your method $_GET to $_POST like below

```
$ownid = $_POST['field1'];
$interestid =$_POST['field2'];

$query = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE tablem SET field1= ? WHERE field2= ?");
$query -> bindValue(1, $ownid);
$query -> bindValue(2, $interestid);
$query -> execute();
```

i hope this will help you.